# Why this application controller won't return correct value to controller who called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why do I get empty when I execute this? Asumming User's point is 2500. It should return 83

**posts_controller**

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.percentage = count_percentage(@user)
@user.save
```

**application_controller**

```
def count_percentage(user)
    if user

        if user.point > 2999
            percentage = ((user.point / 5000.0) * 100 ).to_i
        elsif user.point > 1999
            percentage = ((user.point / 3000.0) * 100 ).to_i
        end

        return percentage

    end
end
```

Comment: I think `count_percentage` belongs to your `User` model and not into a controller method since it is tied to your user. Unless you are using presenters, then it may be something for your presenter class.

Comment: Where exactly did you get empty?

Comment: @PaulChechetin Can't I use that in application_controller? What should I do instead?

Comment: @PaulChechetin What do you mean? I got empty only in  percentage column in users table

Comment: @pduersteler `count_percentage` will be called from `side menu` which is shown in every page

Comment: @HUSTEN You code seems to logically valid.

Comment: What is your User's point column type? Is it integer or varchar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is some lack of basic understanding, so I try to focus on a few points here.

**`count_percentage` belongs to your model**. It is a method which does things that are tied to your `User` records. In your example, the code can only be used with a `User` record. Therefore it belongs to your `User` class!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def percentage
    if self.point > 2999
        return ((self.point / 5000.0) * 100 ).to_i
    elsif user.point > 1999
        return ((self.point / 3000.0) * 100 ).to_i
    else
        # personally, I'd add a case for points range 0...3000
    end
  end
```

As you said, you want to put that value into your "side menu", so this allows to e.g `@user.percentage` there which gives you the desired percentage.

According to your description (if I understood it the right way) you want to store the calculated value in your user model. And here we go again: **Model logic belongs into your model class**. If you want to keep your percentage value up to date, you'd add a callback, like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :store_percentage

  def precentage
    # your code here
  end


  private

  def store_percentage
    self.my_percentage_field_from_my_database = self.percentage
  end
end
```

To your actual problem: `user.point` may be `NULL` (db) / `nil` (ruby), so you should convert it `to_i` before actually calculating with it. Also that's why I've suggested an `else` block in your condition; To return a value wether or not your `user.point` is bigger than `1999` (if it even is an integer.. which I doubt in this case).

Answer (score 1):

To answer on this question you should try to examine `user.point`, `percentage` value in the `count_percentage` method.

I strongly recommend [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry). Because it's awesome.